# Synchranization issue in async jobs created and finished before main thread ends

Tags: architecture, ruby-on-rails, synchronization, async

Main execution thread creates asynchronous job (started and executed by different process) that works on same data that the main thread. For example we create some database entries, that we want to process asynchronously later, but choose not to do it in main thread. This creates a situation when main execution thread may not finish before async jobs start running and potentially finish before main thread. This means that job can run on non-existent or old data and the result may be wrong.

My current solution has been to create jobs with delay, so that they start with set delay. This is classifies as not very good workaround, since the need to explicitly define such delay. In my current tech stack job descriptions (job classes) are uncoupled from how jobs are created (setting delays for example)). Always there is problem to pick the right delay. In some cases job can run minutes after the main thread, but in some cases the delay should be as small as possible.

One thought I had, but it seems bit complex to implement: every database record has `updated_at` column which can be compared to `async_job_started_at`. Problem with this approach is that there may exist jobs that we want to run old data and we need to implement sort of `force_execution` flag on jobs. Overall: seems very clunky solution.

Another solution, which is also not ideal, is to make execution of those problematic places explicitly synchronous.

I'm trying to find a better way how to solve this issue without too big architectural changes and was thinking that this must be quite typical problem to have. How have you solved this issue?

Tech stack: Rails + Sidekiq. I tagged the question as ruby-on-rails, although I'm guessing this is more general issue. But some tooling may have in-built ways how to avoid this issue.

Constraint: Using ActiveRecords call-backs is not very good solution, since our business logic is living outside of AR models. I was thinking about more general solution.